# Silently discard writes to mmap region

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

I have a Linux device driver which allows a userspace process to `mmap()` certain regions of the device's MMIO space for writing. The device may at some point decide to revoke access to the region, and will notify the driver when this happens. The driver (asynchronously) notifies the userspace process to stop using this region.

I'd like the driver to immediately zap the PTEs for this mapping so they can be returned to device control, however, the userspace process might still be finishing a write. I'd like to simply discard these writes. The user does not need to know which writes made it to the device and which writes were discarded. What can the driver's fault handler do after zapping the PTEs that can discard writes to the region harmlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the userspace process to make progress, the PTE needs to end up pointing to a writeable page.

If you don't want it writing to your device MMIO region, this implies you'll need to allocate a page of normal memory for the write to go to, just like the fault handler does for an anonymous VMA.

Alternatively, you could let your userspace task take a `SIGBUS` when this revocation event occurs, and just specify that a task using this device should expect this to happen and must install a `SIGBUS` handler that uses `longjmp()` to cancel its attempt to write to the device.  The downside of this approach - apart from the additional complexity it dumps onto userspace - is that it makes using your device difficult from a library, as signal handlers are process-global state.

Comment: I think this sort of misses the goal - you are assuming a level of determinism which may be traditional, but isn't really what the asker seems to be seeking.  In effect, I think they are seeking a "lie and say you did the write even though you didn't" type of *silent failure* - a kind of thing that makes a lot of sense to hardware people but less so in software traditions.

Comment: That's the idea behind replacing the PTE with one that points at an ordinary page of memory, though - the write has "failed" in the sense that it didn't go to the device, but won't fault.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I wanted to avoid `SIGBUS`ing the user, for the very reasons you say.